# How can you return a node from a recursive algorithm?

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

Once I find the value that corresponds to the node key, I just need to return that node to where it was called.

```
MovieNode *found = searchRecursive(root, title);
```

Based on my `cout` statements, it is getting discovered, but when I print it back in `main()`, I am getting gibberish. Interestingly, the node isn't null when it is printed in `main()`, but it is printing the question mark icon many times and a few numbers.

```
struct MovieNode{
    int ranking;
    std::string title;
    int year;
    int quantity;
    MovieNode *parent;
    MovieNode *left;
    MovieNode *right;

    MovieNode(){};

    MovieNode(int in_ranking, std::string in_title, int in_year, int in_quantity)
    {
        ranking = in_ranking;
        title = in_title;
        year = in_year;
        quantity = in_quantity;
        parent = NULL;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};

MovieNode* MovieTree:: searchRecursive(MovieNode *node, std::string value)
{
    if(node->left != NULL){
        searchRecursive(node->left, value);
    }

    if(node->title == value){ //in order
        cout<<"found"<<endl;
        cout<<node->title<<endl;
        return node;
        }

    if(node->right != NULL){
        searchRecursive(node->right, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Free clue: how do you *return* something from any function. Forget about recursive functions. We're talking about any function, and how one would *return* something from it. There's nothing special or magical about recursive functions. They *return* something exactly the same way that non-recursive function *return* something. So, how would you *return* something from a function? Once you answer this question, how you *return* something from a function, you will be able to figure out what you're missing.

Comment: If that was a sarcastic call for me to add a return, it is in the if statement.

Comment: With your if statement ordering won't this just traverse the list to the left most item and if that item isn't your desired value bounce back and forth between your second to left most and left most list items recursing each time.

Comment: And when you make a recursive call, `searchRecursive(node->left, value);`, for example, where exactly do you *return* that particular *return* value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function implementation has undefined behavior. First of all the node can be equal to nullptr and secondly the function in some paths returns nothing.

The function can be defined the following way

```
MovieNode * MovieTree::searchRecursive(MovieNode *node, const std::string &value)
{
    if ( node )
    {
        if ( value < node->title )
        {
            node = searchRecursive(node->left, value);
        }
        else if ( node->title < value )
        {
            node = searchRecursive(node->right, value);
        }
    }

    return node;
}
```

I suppose that the tree is ordered according to the data member title.

Comment: Why do you think the tree is sorted?

Comment: @Yakk I do not see a sense to define an unsorted tree.

Comment: The key difference was node = searchRecusive. In previous assignments, i was able to be recursive without having to return anything directly to itself. The difference then was that it was a void recursive algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

instead of just calling `searchRecursive(...)` do this:

```
auto* r = searchRecusive(...)
if (r) return r;
```

at the end of the function

```
return nullptr;
```

so you get:

```
MovieNode* MovieTree::searchRecursive(MovieNode* node, std::string const& value) {
  if(node->left != nullptr) {
    auto* r = searchRecursive(node->left, value);
    if (r) return r;
  }

  if(node->title == value){ //in order
    std::cout<<"found\n";
    std::cout<<node->title<<std::endl;
    return node;
  }

  if(node->right != nullptr) {
    auto* r = searchRecursive(node->right, value);
    if (r) return r;
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

with a few other minor fixes.

Comment: Where would that first part go? I don't understand. This'll probably get downvoted but I don't know. I see your edit now.

Comment: @user7554736 Compile with C++11 or 14 enabled.  It is 2017.  `-std=c++11` works in gcc/clang I believe.

Comment: @user7554736 The real crux of the issue here is not using auto, but that you need a return statement in each if statement, otherwise you're very likely to end up in an infinite recursive loop.

Comment: @Tuffwer that was it. Thank you.